# Spring Restemplate response with %20 instaed spaces

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm tried to use Restemplate to make a simple GET call, the response give me a String text that contains some spaces, the problem is that instead spaces, it give me %20. Can anyone help me please?

This is my code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String profanityUrl = "https://www.purgomalum.com/service/json";
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder .fromUriString(profanityUrl).queryParam("text", "some text");
    ResponseDTO response = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.toUriString(), ResponseDTO.class);
```

The ResponseDTO is :

```
public class ResponseDTO {

  private String result;
  public String getResult() {
    return result;
  }
  public void setResult(String result) {
     this.result = result;
  }
}
```

And the **result** atribute gives me: **'some%20text'** instead of 'some text' (with the space)

Comment: this is what it suppose to give, as the text has to be URL compatible, and spaces are not allowed in the URL

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to just decode the result value

```
private String decodeResponse(String response) {
    try {
        return URLDecoder.decode(response, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! it woks.